# Осуществить параллельный подсчет на Java

Tags: eclipse, java, распараллеливание

Постановка задачи : написать приложение, реализующее параллельный подсчет вычисления квадрата евклидовой нормы матрицы C=AxB, который определяется формулой

[image: img]

реализовала последовательный подсчет, не могу распараллелить, как поняла, можно разделить столбцы первой матрицы на два потока и осуществить параллельное перемножение со строками второй матрицы, покажите как это можно осуществить, читала про потоки, не знаю как здесь это сделать, с явой познакомилась неделю как.

```
import java.util.*;  

public class ProgamM {  

static Scanner reader=new Scanner(System.in);  
static long s;    

public static void main(String[] args) {   
int m,n,k,l,z;  
System.out.println("Введите размеры первой матрицы(Сначала количество строк, затем - столбцов)");  
m=reader.nextInt();   
n=reader.nextInt();   
System.out.println("Введите размеры второй матрицы");  
l=reader.nextInt();   
k=reader.nextInt();   
int [][] matrixA= new int[m][n];  
int [][] matrixB= new int[l][k];  
if(n!=l)  
{  
System.out.println("Ошибка! Перемножение матриц невозможно");  
return;  
}  
System.out.println("Введите элементы первой матрицы");  
for(int i=0;i<m;i++)  
{  
for(int j=0;j<n;j++)  
{  
matrixA[i][j]=reader.nextInt();  
}  
}  
System.out.println("Введите элементы второй матрицы");  
for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
{
for(int j=0;j<k;j++)
{
matrixB[i][j]=reader.nextInt();
}
}

s=0;  
for(int i=0;i<m;i++)  
{  
for(int j=0;j<k;j++)  
{  
z=0;  
for(int q=0;q<n;q++)  
{  
z+=matrixA[i][q]*matrixB[q][j];  
}  
s+=Math.pow(z, 2);  
}  
}  
System.out.println("Квадрат Eвклидовой нормы равен: \n" + s);  
// TODO Auto-generated method stub  
}  

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Опишу общую схема распараллеливания "в лоб"

1. Создаем N параллельных потоков - каждый поток по сути это объект класса `Thread` или объект класса реализующего интерфейс `Runnable`
2. При создании потока передаем вместе с конструктором данные с которыми поток будет работать (в вашем случае это столбцы видимо)
3. Запускаем потоки через `Thread.start()`
4. Ждем завершения потоков
5. Собираем до кучи результаты
6. Профит

Подсказка: самое сложное здесь это п.4 - по другому это называется проблемой синхронизации потоков. Более подробно [смотрите здесь](http://www.csa.ru/CSA/tutor/javathread.html)